# Is there any effect if I canceled a site move in Google search console and reconfigured it again?

Tags: google-search-console, search, site-move

I have used the move tool in google console to move from site A to site B
But I didn't get any effect for 6 months!

Also, this notification does not appear at the top of the property!although it appears in the search console settings.

[image]

- Do you think If I decided to remove the property then add it again Will it affect the previous move process?
- Is the move tool is mandatory or it's enough to use 301 direction!
- What's your advice for a site had moved for 6 months and there's not affect in search although the redirect is configured properly!

> The old URL: `https://blog.example.com`
> The new URL: `https://spgeeks.example.com`